# Using standard Id field in comparings

Tags: apex

Can I be sure during comparing results with IDs?
Let's say I have 2 List ordered by Ids. And I want to try to find Id in second list by the value from first list using `dichotomy`. Is it possible to compare Ids?

Comment: What is "dichotomy"? What are the types of the lists involved? Can you share some sample code to show what you're trying?

Comment: Type of the List is SObject. Basically Dichotomy is the approach to quick finding some value by `dividing` list to 2  and make a decision which part to use

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific about how you expect things to work when using non-standard terminology relative to the Salesforce ecosystem. Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. That's not what comments are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a binary search is unusual in Apex.

You can, and should, use Maps instead:

```
sObject[] list1 = getList1();
sObject[] list2 = getList2();
Map<Id, sObject> mapOfList2 = new Map<Id, Sobject>(list2);
for(sObject record: list1) {
  sObject recordFromList2 = mapOfList2.get(record.Id);
  if(recordFromList2 != null) {
    System.debug('Found record from list 1 in list 2');
  } else {
    System.debug('Did not find record from list 1 in list 2');
  }
}
```

You'll want to read more about [Maps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm) and their use in Apex.

That said, if you really wanted to do a binary search, you *can*, as long as the list is sorted by Id. This is just like how you can search any other data type, including ordinary strings, in basically any language. It's just highly unusual to do so, as Maps are much more efficient than any algorithm you could devise in Apex.

Comment: sfdcfox, when it comes to binary search  - could we use List or Set instead of Map  in order that there is need to check (or find) only Id?

Comment: You can also do this without (explicit) loops by using the `retainAll()` or `removeAll()` set methods on the keyset of the map. Given you have populated two maps `m1` and `m2`, `Map<Id, SObject> conjunction = m1.clone(); conjunction.keySet().retainAll(m2.keySet());`